# Flutter run app using emulator not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[image: Hello anyone help this error i want to run my app using emulator but show error]

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\flutterapplication\testflutter\build\app\outputs\flutter-

apk\app.apk:
```

Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.endsWith(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:968)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:179)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageM
Error launching application on G011A.